# Spring cloud discovery first does not work at all

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I try to implement a spring cloud netflix project with a eureka service registry, a configuration server and a client microservice.
I use spring cloud finchley release.

I have two problems:
1. Eureka and configuration server are both running, but do not recognize each other. I have read the official [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html) and multiple tutorials, but it does not work. Here is my code:

ConfigServerApplication:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml of config server:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:shared
  profiles:
    active: native

server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

build.gradle of config server:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// let a BOM (Bill Of Materials) handle dependency versions that work together
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // for SpringApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot'
    // for @SpringBootApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    // @EnableConfigServer
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-config-server'
}
```

The service registry application code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServiceRegistryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml from eureka:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

build.gradle from eureka:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// let a BOM (Bill Of Materials) handle dependency versions that work together
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE'
    }
}

// define the dependencies here
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server'
    // for SpringApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot'
    // for @SpringBootApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    // @EnableDiscoveryServer and @EnableDiscoveryClient
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-config-server'
}
```

Both apps run fine, but the config server doesn't registrate itself, any advice?

The second problem:
On starting the other microservice which should registrate first at eureka and then getting from there the address of the config server, it gives the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-04 14:50:34.435 ERROR 28364 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method configServerInstanceProvider in org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' in your configuration.

2018-07-04 14:50:34.440 ERROR 28364 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'instanceProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerInstanceProvider' defined in org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerInstanceProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at de.tudresden.inf.rn.amcs.microservices.courseservice.CourseServiceApplication.main(CourseServiceApplication.java:13) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerInstanceProvider' defined in org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerInstanceProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

The build.gradle of this service:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// let a BOM (Bill Of Materials) handle dependency versions that work together
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // for SpringApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot'
    // for @SpringBootApplication
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    // @EnableDiscoveryServer and @EnableDiscoveryClient
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-config-server'
    // @EnableFeignClients
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-netflix-core'
    // CrudRepository
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa'
    // @EnableFeignClients
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

bootstrap.yml of this service:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: course-service
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-server

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

the application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class MicroServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It would be really nice, if someone could at least provide some hints or advices what to do.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Eureka Server is not configured correctly.

Try to replace:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

with this:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```