# Custom DiscoveryClient for to discover Spring Cloud Config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am trying to build my own `DiscoveryClient` that would use Docker Swarm as the service source.  I got it working with Spring Cloud Gateway and Spring Cloud Loadbalancer already.  However, when I tried to use it to do discovery for the `configserver` by setting `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true` I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at l
east 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I have created AutoConfigure classes as well but no luck.  The project is here https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo.

When looking at the debug logs, with and without the discovery, it appears that the `AutoConfiguration` beans do not load up in the **CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT** specifically the ones in other libraries.

Similar to [Spring cloud discovery first does not work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174668/spring-cloud-discovery-first-does-not-work-at-all) but they are using Eureka, whereas I am trying to determine how to build my own DiscoveryClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a separate set of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguratio` elements in `spring.factory` called `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration`

So I added this

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
net.trajano.spring.swarm.discovery.DockerSwarmDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration
```

And this class

```java
@ConditionalOnClass(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled")
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Import({
    DockerSwarmDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class,
    // this emulates
    // @EnableDiscoveryClient, the import
    // selector doesn't run before the
    // bootstrap phase
    DockerClientConfiguration.class,
    DockerSwarmDiscoveryAutoConfiguration.class,
    DockerSwarmReactiveDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class,
    ReactiveCommonsClientAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class DockerSwarmDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your [Configuration class for the DiscoveryClient](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/master/spring-cloud-docker-swarm/src/main/java/net/trajano/spring/swarm/discovery/DockerSwarmDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java) has these annotations:

```
@ConditionalOnDiscoveryEnabled
@ConditionalOnBlockingDiscoveryEnabled
@ConditionalOnDockerSwarmDiscoveryEnabled
@AutoConfigureAfter({
    DockerSwarmDiscoveryAutoConfiguration.class
})
@AutoConfigureBefore({
    SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class,
    CommonsClientAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

**Could it be those settings are not enabled?** 
You mention you enabled discovery, but you do not mention the other ConditionOnX configurations.
If they are not enabled, the bean would not load.

Comment: If that were the case then the Discovery Client routes shouldn't work either.  It is only failing on the discovery of the configuration server, but not as a discovery client.